# Why Wordpress htaccess rewrite rule not working for parked domain?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

For a main domain (.nl) everything is forced over https and www.
However there is a small bug with parked domain .be

when accessed like https://domain.be/example the www. is not added.
In all other cases it is working.

.htaccess i have so far is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Any ideas would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to check this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Almost there... when entered https://domain.be/extenson) the rewrite goes to the main domain (https://www.domain.be), not to https://www.domain.be/offer.